# F# strange type error message

Tags: types, f#, typeerror, discriminated-union

Can anyone tell me what the following error message means in F#:

```
Program.fs(1021,16): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    FSI_0051.ExprTree
but here has type
    FSI_0061.ExprTree
```

It was the result of executing the following function:

```
let evaluate_tree tree =
    let rec helper tree =
        match tree with
        | Value(x) -> Value(x)
        | Node(l, op, r) -> evaluate (helper l) op (helper r)
    get_float (helper tree)
```

Line 1021 is the last line in the above function. In addition, I declared the following functions and types, before `evaluate_tree`:

```
type Operator =
    | Plus
    | Minus
    | Mult
    | Divide

type ExprTree =
    | Value of float
    | Node of ExprTree * Operator * ExprTree
    static member (-) (a, b) =
        match (a, b) with
        | (Value(x), Value(y)) -> Value(x - y)
    static member (+) (a, b) =
        match (a, b) with
        | (Value(x), Value(y)) -> Value(x + y)
    static member (/) (a, b) =
        match (a, b) with
        | (Value(x), Value(y)) -> Value(x/y)
    static member (*) (a, b) =
        match (a, b) with
        | (Value(x), Value(y)) -> Value(x*y)
```

Note that in the function below, when I did not add the line that says `Node(_,_,_) -> 0.0` (commented), it gave the above error message. However, when I added that line, the error message went away (still I'd like to know what the error message means):

```
let get_float value =
    match value with
    | Value(x) -> x
    //| Node(_, _, _) -> 0.0

let evaluate (value1 : ExprTree) operator (value2 : ExprTree) =
    match operator with
    | Plus -> value1 + value2
    | Minus -> value1 - value2
    | Mult -> value1*value2
    | Divide -> value1/value2

let evaluate_tree tree =
    let rec helper tree =
        match tree with
        | Value(x) -> Value(x)
        | Node(l, op, r) -> evaluate (helper l) op (helper r)
    get_float (helper tree)
```

As a further note: `evaluate_tree` evaluates an expression tree. The expression tree contains the types defined in `ExprTree: Value and Node`. I think it might have to do with me not providing the case in `get_float` for when it's a `Node` (which I accounted for eventually). However, `get_float` will never evaluate a `Node`, not with the way I am using it, unless the tree is wrong (i.e. it will have an operator as a leaf node).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the error message means that in F# interactive there is a conflict between 2 versions of the ExprTree types early evaluated in interactive session. Try to reset interactive session and reevaluate all values in the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is caused by the fact, that each evaluation that execute in the FSI actually creates a dynamic assembly FSI_XXXX. So in fact, your function that you defined with `ExprTree` was maybe referring to `FSI_0051.ExprTree` whereas a function that you defined later and used `ExprTree` is now referring to `FSI_0061.ExprTree`.

What I typically do to fix the error, is just execute the definition of all my functions using `ExprTree` again, now that there is a newer `FSI_0061.ExprTree` and all should work.

You simply need to be aware, that each new evaluation with the same name will *shadow* the pre-existing symbol. On the other hand, they are still distinct symbols, hence the two names `FSI_0051.ExprTree` and `FSI_0061.ExprTree`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So you mean that the first time I executed the **definition** for `ExprTree`, it created `FSI_0051.ExprTree`, and the second time, `FSI_0061.ExprTree`? Then the error obviously came up because I defined some functions and variables before defining the second one, and some after defining the second one. Then the ones that I have defined after the second one expected `FSI_0061.ExprTree`, but the other variables/functions still operated on `FSI_0051.ExprTree`?

Comment: Ya pretty much. Basically type names are resolved at evaluation time of the definition. So unless you were generic, the "old" type is used.